# MVC - Dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I just started doing MVC 4 and I've been enjoying it quite a bit, but I'm running into trouble when I'm trying to get my database (just NAME and EMAIL entries) to show all its entries in the index view. I get the following error:

> *The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MobileWebFormver2.Models.WebForm1]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MobileWebFormver2.Models.User]'*.

I was able to connect the program to the database, but I'm pretty much stuck here. I was wondering if I could get some help. Here's my code:

**User Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 

namespace MobileWebFormver2.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter name.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter email.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HomeController** (WebForm1 is a database entry, that contains a NAME and EMAIL field)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MobileWebFormver2.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MobileWebFormver2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "This is the TourEast Holidays Mobile Index";

            return View(db.WebForm1s.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

**Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<MobileWebFormver2.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

EDIT: This refers to DataClasses1DataContext. I'm not sure how useful this will be.

**DataClasses1.cs**

```
namespace MobileWebFormver2.Models
{
    partial class DataClasses1DataContext
    {
    }
}
```

**DataClasses1.designer.cs**

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.269
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MobileWebFormver2.Models
{
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;


[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="MobileWebForm")]
public partial class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{

    private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnCreated();
partial void InsertWebForm1(WebForm1 instance);
partial void UpdateWebForm1(WebForm1 instance);
partial void DeleteWebForm1(WebForm1 instance);
#endregion

    public DataClasses1DataContext() : 
            base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MobileWebFormConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataClasses1DataContext(string connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataClasses1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataClasses1DataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataClasses1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public System.Data.Linq.Table<WebForm1> WebForm1s
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<WebForm1>();
        }
    }
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.WebForm1")]
public partial class WebForm1 : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private string _Name;

    private string _Email;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnNameChanging(string value);
partial void OnNameChanged();
partial void OnEmailChanging(string value);
partial void OnEmailChanged();
#endregion

    public WebForm1()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Name", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false, IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Name != value))
            {
                this.OnNameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Name = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Name");
                this.OnNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Email", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Email;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Email != value))
            {
                this.OnEmailChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Email = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Email");
                this.OnEmailChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
 #pragma warning restore 1591'
```

I looked at similar posts here and I know it has to do with passing an object, but the view is expecting something else. However I would say I'm a very beginner level programmer and I don't think I understood most of what they were saying. I basically followed the code from the MVC tutorial site ([Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-model%27s-data-from-a-controller)) from Microsoft on how to show your database in the index, but I'm getting the error. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of DbContext? You'll need a DbSet<User> to query against.

Comment: Can you provide me instructions on how to show the implentation? My apologies, I'm a true beginner haha. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I went to to my models and there is a DataClasses1.dbml. I right clicked it and clicked view code and now I am in DataClasses1.cs. in the code all there is is:                                   namespace MobileWebFormver2.Models
{
    partial class DataClasses1DataContext
    {
    }
} @LeonCullens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the wrong thing into the view.  You're passing a collection of `WebForm1`'s, not `User`'s.

Edit - 
Change your view model to this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MobileWebFormver2.Models.WebForm1>
```

Edit - a bit more explanation:

On this line, you are creating the ActionResult and passing in the data for the model.

```
return View(db.WebForm1s.ToList());
```

However, db.WebForm1s is a collection of type `WebForm1`.

In your view, you are making a strongly typed view when you declare the model:

```
@model IEnumerable<MobileWebFormver2.Models.User>
```

The view expects a collection of users, but is passed WebForm1 instead.  Hence the error - you have to decide which one is correct, the controller passing in WebForm1, or the view, and change the other to match.

Comment: Assuming that DataClasses1DataContext contains a DbSet<User> called Users of course.

Comment: Indeed, I'm just assuming since he didn't show his database context, but seemed a reasonable assumption.

Comment: could I ask how you get DataClasses1DataContext to contain DbSet<User>? When I tried adding db.Users.ToList(), it didn't compile. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm quite new to programming especially object-oriented. I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Heh, guess my assumption was off.  Can you please post the code for your DbContext?  That would help.  The core issue though is still that you are giving the view a list of WebForm1, but the view expects a list of users.

Comment: Is it the code in DataClasses1.cs? The code is empty, it just says partial class DataClasses1DataContext { }

Comment: Ah, so you're using database first from an edmx? You need to find the other half of that partial.

Comment: yeah I created the local database first in SQL Server Management Studio called MobileWebForm and then created a table called WebForm1 with NAME and EMAIL entries. How do I find the other half of that partial? Once again, I like to thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Alright - edited answer again.  Fix the view model and it should be okay.

Comment: haha ty it works! Wow Thanks again, I really appreciate it! Can I ask why the method in the MVC tutorial (I added the link at the end of my question) in worked, but mine didn't? I know they used code-first to create the database.

Comment: Once again - the issue is miss-matched types.  In the controller, you gave the view a collection of WebForm1.  The view wanted a collection of Users (`IEnumerable<MobileWebFormver2.Models.User>`) .  WebForm1 != User.  It can't magically make WebForm1 into a User, so it throws an exception.